# Code snippet ends with triple backticks

Tags: support, bug, markdown

On [my question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/543804/154990), the very last code snippets ends with the triple backticks "```".

The same exact code snippet on StackOverflow does NOT end with the triple backticks (I thought I erred with the Markdown code somehow and tried to post on StackOverflow). Those backticks are only visible on CrossValidated and here.

Maybe some Markdown misconfiguration on this side?

Here is the code snippet:

```
> table(df$y, df$gender)

         0      1
  0 194276  88007
  1    995    237
```

Comment: If you add a break, they will disappear.

Comment: @FransRodenburg you are right :) Thanks

Comment: @FransRodenburg feel free to add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to happen if a code chunk is the last part of a post. You can get rid of it by adding a line break after the final code chunk.

Comment: Definitely a bug